# Best way to fix a seed to loop K-means image segmentation through large images

Tags: python, opencv, k-means

Pardon me for my newbie image question. I have a huge set of pathology images (approx. 750 mb each). I am trying to do color-based multi-class segmentation on few representative images to create labels, to be passed on later for a model for more robust analysis.

I tried to do some thresholding, but some elements are very close to each other, and small thresholding difference tends to be unstable when looping through multiple images. So, my steps are something like:

1. separate image by cv2.split()
2. use a representative layer to so thersholding the color space
3. run cv2.kmeans() to find the separate the similar reminant objects.

The problem is those images are very large, and cv2.kmeans() fails with the error of "python segmentation fault". If I break the image into tiles, not all tiles will have the same objects, so kmeans will just segment any thing any way.

Second problem, I want to repeat the k-means algorithm on many images to keep giving consistent labels everytime, so I think I have to test on one of them then set center, but on opencv-python, I cannot find any way to set the k-means center manually.

So, how can I efficiently pass large image to kmeans? and how can I fix the centers/seed through many images?

[image: Reference sample for what I am dealing with]

Comment: "Second problem" -- OK, you definitely need to split this up. One question at a time, and keep it very focused.

Comment: And add one more, purely focused on the "python segmentation fault" bit. What version of OpenCV? What platform, OS (I guess some *nix given it's segfault)? 32 or 64 bit? Can you make a [mcve] that recreates that?